# HTML - Redirection

Tags: iis, proxy, redirect

I have three Domains that resolve to the same Public IP Address but I want each domain to be redirected to a different IIS servers within my network. Lets I have the following domains and I want the request to be redirected to a particular internal IP Address

```
     Domain1.com ---> private IP 192.168.20.1
     Domain2.com ---> private IP 192.168.20.2
     Domain3.com ---> private IP 192.168.20.1
```

What is e best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be better off on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to set these up for serving multiple domains on the same public ip.

I myself use [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) it to serve aoeu.se, aioobe.org, multri.net on the same public IP. [Here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/06/17/lighttpd-as-reverse-proxy/) is a tutorial on how to set this up.

Comment: Thanks, I am finally making the jump from VB6 into the Dot Net arena.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS, you can try http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/

Watch a video here:
http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting

HTH